# *.Designer.cs file is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and when I create a form, I get a `FormName.Designer.cs` file with all the auto generated code.

This is exactly what I want, however, when I do the following:

1. Created an empty class.
2. Subclass `System.Windows.Forms.Control`
3. Add a `System.Windows.Forms.ImageList` to the designer.
4. Add images to the ImageList in the designer.

All of the auto generated code gets dropped in my class file and I don't get a `*.Designer.cs` file.

How do I get VS to always use a `*.Designer.cs` file?

---

**Update**

Declaring a class partial and subclassing UserControl is not sufficient. I had to select "UserControl" when I created a new Item, then I got a designer.cs file.

Comment: VS will only create one if it's part of the template of the item. Haven't tested this, but I know that if you create a designer file manually (if all goes well) is collapses into the relevant parent, in this case it should use the file.

Comment: @sneakthief, It isn't creating the designer.cs file, that is the problem. I want one. I have a Design view I can drag controls on from the toolbox, but no designer.cs file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal and the way the designer worked in versions of Visual Studio before VS2005, versions that did not yet support *partial classes*.  You only get the separate Designer.cs file for a class that's derived from Form or UserControl **and** you declared them with the partial keyword.

Not 100% sure what's the underlying reason, but surely it has something to do with the very simple designer for the Control class.  The designers for Form and UserControl are much fancier.

Nothing actually goes wrong so this is not a real problem.  There is very little bang for the buck, especially since it is so uncommon to actually need another component or control when you create a custom control.  Getting the Properties window to work is a convenience but, in my personal experience, isn't worth the considerable annoyance of getting the designer page by default when you double-click the class in the Solution Explorer window.  I lost count of the number of times I shouted "crud!" at the machine.